# How to update the activity which is not finished?

Tags: android, singleton, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am developing an app where I want to update the value of the particular product count.

1.In main menu there are sliding tabs, where I will be having list of products with plus and minus to add that particular product to the cart.I am preserving the count using singleton class.

2.Now I am clicking on the search button on the same activity,where I am searching the same product which I have already added in the cart.Only the count value of that particular product will get increase and updated in the singleton class.

3.When i click black from the search,the previous activity(i.e main menu activity) comes to the UI with the previous count.If i finish the previous activity before going to the search activity and then if i call the main activity when back is pressed from search everything will be updated.

4.Here what i am doing is on click of search,I am calling the search activity without finishing the main activity.On click of back from the search activity only search activity is finishing.

How can i change the value of the particular product when coming back from search activity?

```
iv_search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchProduct.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.move_up, R.anim.stay);
        }
    });

iv_backsr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();

        }
    });
```

hope you guys understand what I am trying to say here..tell me if you need any code.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: please write some comment before you are making this question negative.

Comment: I am not able to figure out exactly what you require. Do you want to refresh the activity to update its contents?

Comment: yes..,'simple as that

Comment: Try using finish(); and startActivity(getIntent());

Answer (score 0):

Asif, in your first activity move your product count logic e.g. showing current product count from the singleton to the onResume() method. In this way when you return from the search activity values will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting another activity, modifying some values, and expecting to see the new result in your original activity. This is possible if you use `startActivityforResult()` instead of `startActivity()`. Take a look at the Android documentation on how to use this. 
You will have to start the search activity as startactivityforresult and override `onActivityResult()` in your MainActivity.
Ideally, you will be passing the name/id or some other unique identifier of the item and the required count back to your original activity.

Comment: Am I want to use any local broadcast receiver instead??